# React Typescript pass state

Tags: state, react-typescript

I am new to React TypeScript. I have a problem with the passing state. When I tried to pass the state to a child component and conosle.log(state), I can see the correct object. But, when I tried to do console.log(state.name), I have an error. How can I solve this problem?

App.tsx

```html
export interface Information {
  name: string;
  age: string;
}

const App: FC = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState<Information | null>({
    name: "young",
    age: "10",
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="header">
        <div className="inputContainer">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Task.." name="task" />
          <input type="number" placeholder="Deadline" name="deadline" />
        </div>
        <button>Add Task</button>
        <div>
          <MyForm state={state} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Child component

```html
type Props = {
  state: ReactNode;
};

const MyForm: FC<Props> = ({ state }: Props) => {
  console.log(state.name);  // Error
  return <div>Hello, {state}</div>;
};

export default MyForm;
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide the error? what does `console.log(state)` produce?

Comment: console.log(state) shows name and age well as object. but console.log(state.name) shows "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name, age}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error because you're trying to read the `state` object inside `JSX`

```js
  return <div>Hello, {state}</div>
```

Read it like you would with objects instead:

```js
  return <div>Hello, {state.name}</div>
```

Also in your `MyForm` Component *Props*, use your `Information` interface as a type definition instead of `ReactNode`

```js
export interface Information {
  name: string
  age: string
}

type Props = {
  state: Information
}
```

[image: Edit holy-sunset-30f9j]

Comment: Thank you! Now I got this!